# Thri-Kreen Chameleon Chitin

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth, thri-kreen

I have a question based on the wording of the Thri-Kreen power Chameleon Chitin:

> **Effect**: You make a Stealth check. If you have any cover or concealment, you gain a +5 power bonus to this check. You can remain hidden without cover or concealment as long as you make no attacks and you take no action that requires you to make another Stealth check.

Does it mean I don't need to have total concealment or superior cover to make a Stealth check? So I could make a check anywhere?

Or would it need to state this explicitly, and this simply refers to a normal Stealth check with the above mentioned superior concealment and cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In 4e, Specific Beats General**

> Powers, class features, racial traits, feats, magic items, monster abilities, and other game statistics usually include some element that breaks the general rules in some way. The element creates an exception to how the rest of the game works. Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.  - Rules Compendium p. 29

Thus in response to your question, You would be able to make the stealth check and be hidden even though normally you could not. However after using the power, all other, regular stealth rules apply.

Answer (score 2):

This power forces you to roll a Stealth check, no matter where you are, as soon as it's activated. This means you can have no concealmen and the power doesn't care.

Compare "You make a stealth check" with "Use this power while making a stealth check" or "When you make a stealth check, ..."

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

This power allows you to hide without cover or concealment. It basically says at the beginning of the power "you now meet the requirements to roll a stealth check" without actually saying that. The one thing that *does* happen is that you don't have total concealment/superior cover if you happen to fail the stealth check (you become plainly visible again), but it does allow you to become hidden from any monster whose passive perception you beat with your check.

This interpretation is supported by the wording of the power, the conditional bonus, and the second sentence. It's also supported by the flavor text of the power (though that's largely irrelevant).